# How to enter custom font in Custom Keyboard as input

Tags: ios, fonts, ios8, keyboard, ios-app-extension

I am trying to use a font named "KarenThewin". 
I have added this font the keyboard keys and now i want to extract the displayed key.

The character Array : `#define kChar @[ @"n", @"0", @"=J", @"&", @"w", @",", @"=k", @"=X", @"=D", @"y", @"=g", @"q", @"'", @"=m", @"i", @"[", @"*", @"u", @"v", @"-=", @"t", @"C", @"=l", @"b", @"e", @"r", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"" ]`

Once you define the font to KarenThewin you will be able to see the keyboard.

But when i am trying to take input from the keyboard key its returning me the same value mentioned above in the array but it should return me the font specific value.

E.g. if i press the 1st of keybaord it should show the below symbol rather "n"

```
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:[key currentTitle]];
```

[image: image of the keyboard reading from the above array]

Please let me know if some more info is required from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only output your can pass from your keyboard to the system is an unattributed string

Comment: i agree with your point but then how to achieve the above scenario. 
What comes to mind is ask user to install the font and then i hope it will work.. any suggestions.

Comment: hi vinay, have you find any solution?